# Android Studio search bar list view with json data

Tags: java, android, json, listview, search

Im trying to implement search bar to search an idea by title name and then press a button. Lets say I put in the search field the letter T, and clicked search. 
I want the list view to update with only ideas that begin with the letter T.
Can anybody help a brother out? Thanks!

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import ideas.ideasportal.api.Idea;
import ideas.ideasportal.api.JsonHandler;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ViewIdeas extends AppCompatActivity {


public ArrayList<Idea> ideas = new  ArrayList<Idea>();
public ListView ideasList;
Intent viewIdea;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_ideas);

   viewIdea = new Intent(this, ViewIdea.class);

    JsonHandler jsonHandler = new JsonHandler();
    ideas = jsonHandler.handleIdeas((String)getIntent().getExtras().get("ideas"));

    ideasList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Idea idea : ideas)
    {

        arr.add(idea.getTitle());

    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> ar = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, arr);
    ideasList.setAdapter(ar);




    ideasList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Idea idea = ideas.get(position);

            viewIdea.putExtra("id", idea.getId());

                startActivity(viewIdea);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: so, what's the problem?